# Using curl and wget returns a different file format

Tags: curl, wget

I'm trying to download a JSON file from Googledrive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/10A_pBcJxBLDVJk_L_e1HcHsc8hz38Sau/view).

When I use wget (or curl) I downloaded the file, but it is in html.

curl -L -o inventory_keywords_downloaded_adjusted.json  "https://drive.google.com/file/d/13lzO4-4w479kVDx7wxa5mx7x1kxEnUUs/view?usp=sharing"

wget 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/10A_pBcJxBLDVJk_L_e1HcHsc8hz38Sau/view?usp=sharing' -O inventory_keywords_downloaded.json

I either one of those commands should yield a json file, but instead I am getting a html file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Google Drive direct download link instead of the sharing link:

It should be https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=10A_pBcJxBLDVJk_L_e1HcHsc8hz38Sau for the link you posted.

If you only have the links in that format, you could use [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) or some other method to get the ID of the file and put it in the format above.